# Calculate the Inverse DTFT of the DTFT Derivative in Terms of $ x \left[ n \right] $

Tags: fourier-transform, homework, dtft

Consider the signal $ x \left[ n \right] $ and its DTFT transform $ X \left( {e}^{j \omega} \right) $.
Assume $ X \left( {e}^{j \omega} \right) $ is differentiable.

What is the Inverse DTFT of:

$$ j \frac{d}{d \omega} X \left( {e}^{j \omega} \right) $$

Express the result in terms of $ x \left[ n \right] $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward using the definition of the [Discrete Time Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) (DTFT).

The definition of the DTFT:

$$ X \left( {e}^{j \omega} \right) = \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} x \left[ m \right] {e}^{-j \omega m} $$

Differentiating with respect to $\omega$:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{d \omega} X \left( {e}^{j \omega} \right) & =  \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d}{d \omega} x \left[ m \right] {e}^{-j \omega m} \\
& = \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} \left( -j m \right) x \left[ m \right] {e}^{-j \omega m} \\
& = \frac{1}{j} \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} m x \left[ m \right] {e}^{-j \omega m} \\
\end{align*}$$

Now, just plug it into the Inverse DTFT:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{j} \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} m x \left[ m \right] {e}^{-j \omega m} {e}^{j \omega n} d \omega & = \frac{1}{j} \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} m x \left[ m \right] \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} {e}^{-j \omega m} {e}^{j \omega n} d \omega \\
& = \frac{1}{j} \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} m x \left[ m \right] \delta \left[ n - m \right] \\
& = \frac{n}{j} x \left[ n \right]
\end{align*}$$

This implies:

$$ j \frac{d}{d \omega} X \left( {e}^{j \omega} \right) = j \frac{n}{j} x \left[ n \right] = n x \left[ n \right] $$

Comment: With $d\omega$.

Comment: @Gilles, Indeed a typo :-) Fixed it. Thank You.

Comment: Did you forget to multiply by `j` in the end? Also, I think one other way to calculate this would be just by using integration by parts (i.e. you can move derivative of X under d of the integral and switch).

Comment: @DanM., where do you think the $ j $ is missing?

Comment: @Royi the question asks for DTFT of $j$ multiplied by derivative, however you've dropped that. It's trivial to add, but someone might not notice it.

Comment: @DanM. You're correct. I updated it accordingly. Thank You.